# webpack + angular 1.X doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I am trying to use webpack in my existing angularjs [1.4.7] application. I have one custom module which is getting generated as a bundle using webpack. I am later adding that custom module as a dependency in some other module. I don't get any error while generating bundle. But when I use this module as a dependency , it's throwing below error. I have tried everything possible and can't understand what's wrong here.

**Error**
Failed to instantiate module Module2 due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr]..........
This error occurs when a module fails to load due to some exception. The error message above should provide additional context.

A common reason why the module fails to load is that you've forgotten to include the file with the defined module or that the file couldn't be loaded.

**Code Snippet**
**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: [  './src/main/resources/js/app/app.module.js' ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: './src/main/resources/js/app/bundle.js'
    },
    node: {
        module: "empty",
        net:"empty",
        fs: "empty"
    },
    watch: false
};
```

**app.module.js**

'use strict';

```
var angular = require('angular');
module.exports = angular.module('module1', [
    require('./components/services').name,
    require('./components/controllers').name,
    require('./components/directives').name

]);
```

**components/services/index.js**

```
   'use strict';
    var angular = require('angular');    
    module.exports = angular.module('services',[])
        .factory('Service1', require('./Service1'))
        .factory( 'Service2' , require('.Service2'))
```

**components/services/service1.js**

```
 module.exports = function Service1( $q) 
{
  var service1 =  {};
  // service implementation
 return service1;
};
```

**components/controllers/index.js**

```
'use strict';
var angular = require('angular');
module.exports = angular.module('controllers',[])
    .controller('controller1' , require('./controller1'))
    .controller('controller2' , require('./controller2'));
```

**components/directives/index.js**

```
'use strict';
var angular = require('angular');
module.exports = angular.module('directives',['services'])
    .directive('directive1', require('./directive1'))
    .directive('directive2' , require('./directive2'))
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="bundle.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**another app.js**

```
var app2 = angular.module('Module2',['ui.router','ui.bootstrap','module1']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your second module in the entry:

```
entry: {
    app: [  
       './src/main/resources/js/app/app.module.js',
       './src/main/resources/js/app/app.js'
    ]
},
```

It will help defining your module at first. Also I didn't see any reference to module2 in your code.

Comment: 2nd module is a separate project[module in Intellij] hence you don't see any reference here.  This project is added as maven dependency in another project where 2nd module is defined.

Comment: In that case it is probably the order of execution, you have to make sure that your module2 is loaded before module 1 in your dependency graph

Comment: do you see anything wrong here?                                                               node: {
        module: "empty",
        net:"empty",
        fs: "empty"
    },

Comment: didn't get it, would be more useful if you update your question with your maven config or at least a higher level view of how they are linked

Comment: I was talking about the code snippet in webpack.config.js. I will also add the higher level configuration in few mins.

Comment: I found the issue. As I suspected these lines in webpack.config.js were creating issue. node: { module: "empty", net:"empty", fs: "empty" }. I commented this and it's working. The reason I added these lines was because I was planning to use the same webpack.config to compress my antlr javascript runtime and this wiki says to add these 3 lines. https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/javascript-target.md

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me :)